# Is the usage 'biscuit got over' correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is the usage 'biscuit got over' correct meaning biscuits are finished?

Comment: No, absolutely not. But please tell us where you got that idea. Thanks.

Comment: "Correct"?  If you mean *idiomatic*, then no, it's not something most native speakers would say.  But it could be a colorful expression in some local dialect.

Answer (score 1):

No, **got over** does not mean "are finished".  You can say

> The biscuits are done.

to mean that the bake is complete.

You could also holler

> Biscuits are up!

to mean "Come and get one, they're ready to be eaten".

P.S. The word **over** is used of *events* or of things which have duration.

> The football season was over.
>
> The TV show was over.
>
> The dance was over.
>
> Their friendship was over.

It means "to be at an end, to be no longer, to be a thing of the past".

> We should order the product online today, before the "20% off" sale is over.